# Run a job every X days but only between two specific dates and times

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I think the title says it all.

I would like to run a job that e.g. Starts at Jun 19 2014 (say at 7 AM), ends at December 25 2015 (say at 11 PM) and runs every 9 days in between these two dates. I can set it up to work without an end date. But I don't know how to include all of it in one expression.

**Update:** 
Does adding an `EndAt()` to my `TriggerBuilder` work?

```
mytrigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
    .WithCronSchedule(cron)
    .EndAt(xxxx)
    .Build();
```

Comment: Show us your current config

Comment: @Martin I was thinking to mention the start date and time in my cron and then when I add my trigger using `TriggerBuilder` I also add `endAt()`. Is that a good idea?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "mention start date and time in my cron", but setting endAt will ensure that the trigger will not fire after the endAt date

Comment: @Martin what I mean is that I can write my cron so that it starts on a specific date and time. But in order to add the end date I can create a my trigger using `TriggerBuilder` and add the ´endDate´ to its build as well. I will update my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right direction, schedules that need a lot of research to be generated with a cron expression can be easily generated via the API. For example, the trigger you want is the following:

```
    var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 06, 19, 7, 0, 0);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 25, 23, 0, 0);
    var cronExpression = "0 0 12 1/9 * ? *"; //every nine days

    ITrigger trig = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .StartAt(startDate)
        .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression)
        .WithDescription("description")
        .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
        .WithPriority(1)
        .EndAt(endDate)
        .Build();
```

If you want to see the cron expression generated:

```
    ICronTrigger trigger = (ICronTrigger)trig;
    string cronExpression = trigger.CronExpressionString;
```